# SSD upgrade and Lion

Tags: ssd, migration

I have Lion installed in my system (macbook pro 17 mid 2010).
I have also created a Lion DVD using a guide I've found while surfing the Internet.
Tomorrow I will receive a ocz agility 3 240gb ssd drive.
What is the best way to move all of my work to the new ssd drive?
I am a developer and I have numerous ide installed (like netbeans) and servers like glassfish.
It would be a complete disaster if I had to reinstall things, so I am wondering what is the best way to transfer the operating system and the installed applications easily.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Superduper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html), if you can connect the SSD as an external HD before installing it.

Comment: This and an external SATA 2.5" drive enclosure.  On the software side, [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) will also do the same job, but I am also a SuperDuper! user.

Comment: Is it ok if I use time machine backup and then use migration assistant on the new ssd (after Lion installation)?

Comment: You run higher risk. Sometimes restoring from Time Machine does not work (it happened to me). On the other hand I never heard of Superduper not working as advertised.